# Why I get syntax error?

Tags: android

Hi I wrote this code, and I dont understand why give me `syntax error on token "}", delet this token`?

```
private class DemoView extends View{
        public DemoView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }//here***

        final int x = 0;
        final int y = 0;

this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
                switch(e.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    x++;
                    break;
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch drag with the ball
                // move the balls the same as the finger
                    x = x-25;
                    y = y-25;   
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }//here***
         }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple errors:

1. First closing curly brace closed the constructor. Should be at the end of code.
2. `setOnTouchListener()` missed the closing brace.
3. You variables x,y should be fields (instead of automatic variables) so that they can be changed inside anonymous class `View.OnTouchListener`

Here is the corrected code (I hope it does what you intended):

```
public class DemoView extends View {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    public DemoView(Context context) {
        super(context);


        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
                switch (e.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        x++;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   // touch drag with the ball
                        // move the balls the same as the finger
                        x = x - 25;
                        y = y - 25;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }//here***
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited the code to use fields instead a automatic variable of type `MoveData`.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten one `}` at the end of the file. Also the statements after the declaration of two fields aren't contained in any method. You should move them to the constructor.